# Problems developing calendar with JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm developing a calendar from scratch using JS and boostrap and I had a problem when I try to select one of the cells of the calendar.
The calendar is composed by the body(data generated dinamically depending the date selected), two buttons to go previous and back in months and a select to jump into a specific date.

[image]

I'm using the functions removeClass() and addClass() to know which cell is clicked (at the moment only to change it's color), but when I click into "prev" or "next" buttons and the calendar-body charges the new data, **the JS function to detect which cell is clicked is not working**.
[image]
This is the JS code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    "use strict";
    var template = document.title;
    if (template.includes("Timetables Layout")) {
        /*Fecha actual*/
        let today = new Date();
        let currentMonth = today.getMonth();
        let currentYear = today.getFullYear();

        /*Mostrar el calendario*/
        var values = [currentYear - 1, currentYear, currentYear + 1];
        let selectYear = document.getElementById("year");
        selectYear.options[0] = new Option(values[0].toString(), values[0]);
        selectYear.options[1] = new Option(values[1].toString(), values[1]);
        selectYear.options[2] = new Option(values[2].toString(), values[2]);
        let selectMonth = document.getElementById("month");
        let months = ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"];
        let monthAndYear = document.getElementById("monthAndYear");
        showCalendar(currentMonth, currentYear);
        
        /*Eventos para los botones y el select*/
        document.getElementById("previous").addEventListener("click", function() {
            currentYear = (currentMonth === 0) ? currentYear - 1 : currentYear;
            currentMonth = (currentMonth === 0) ? 11 : currentMonth - 1;
            if (values.includes(currentYear)) {
                showCalendar(currentMonth, currentYear);
            }
        });
        document.getElementById("next").addEventListener("click", function() {
            currentYear = (currentMonth === 11) ? currentYear + 1 : currentYear;
            currentMonth = (currentMonth + 1) % 12;
            if (values.includes(currentYear)) {
                showCalendar(currentMonth, currentYear);
            }
        });
        document.getElementById("month").addEventListener("change", function() {
            currentYear = parseInt(selectYear.value);
            currentMonth = parseInt(selectMonth.value);
            showCalendar(currentMonth, currentYear);
        });
        document.getElementById("year").addEventListener("change", function() {
            currentYear = parseInt(selectYear.value);
            currentMonth = parseInt(selectMonth.value);
            showCalendar(currentMonth, currentYear);
        });
        /*Funcion para mostrar el calendario*/
        function showCalendar(month, year) {
            let firstDay = (new Date(year, month)).getDay();
            let daysInMonth = 32 - new Date(year, month, 32).getDate();
            let tbl = document.getElementById("calendar-body"); // body of the calendar
            // clearing all previous cells
            tbl.innerHTML = "";
            // filing data about month and in the page via DOM.
            monthAndYear.innerHTML = months[month] + " " + year;
            selectYear.value = year;
            selectMonth.value = month;
            // creating all cells
            let date = 1;
            for (let i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
                // creates a table row
                let row = document.createElement("tr");
                //creating individual cells, filing them up with data.
                for (let j = 0; j < 7; j++) {
                    if (i === 0 && j < firstDay) {
                        let cell = document.createElement("td");
                        let cellText = document.createTextNode("");
                        cell.appendChild(cellText);
                        row.appendChild(cell);
                    }
                    else if (date > daysInMonth) {
                        break;
                    }
                    else {
                        let cell = document.createElement("td");
                        let cellText = document.createTextNode(date);
                        if (date === today.getDate() && year === today.getFullYear() && month === today.getMonth()) {
                            cell.classList.add("bg-info");
                        } // color today's date
                        cell.appendChild(cellText);
                        row.appendChild(cell);
                        date++;
                    }
                }
                tbl.appendChild(row); // appending each row into calendar body.
            }
        }
        /*Funciones al clicar el calendario*/
        $('td').click(function(){
            $('#calendar-body > tr > td.bg-info').removeClass('bg-info');
            $(this).addClass('bg-info');
            var date = $('#monthAndYear').text();
            console.log(date);
            console.log($(this).text());
        });
    }
});
```

HTML code:

```
<div class="container">
 <h3 class="card-header" id="monthAndYear"></h3>
  <table class="table table-bordered table-responsive-sm" id="calendar">
   <thead>
   <tr>
    <th>Sun</th>
    <th>Mon</th>
    <th>Tue</th>
    <th>Wed</th>
    <th>Thu</th>
    <th>Fri</th>
    <th>Sat</th>
   </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody id="calendar-body">
   </tbody>
  </table>
  <div class="form-inline">
   <button class="btn btn-outline-primary col-sm-6" id="previous" >Previous</button>
   <button class="btn btn-outline-primary col-sm-6" id="next" >Next</button>
  </div>
  <br />
  <form class="form-inline">
   <label class="lead mr-2 ml-2" for="month">Jump To: </label>
   <select class="form-control col-sm-4" name="month" id="month">
    <option value="0">Jan</option>
    <option value="1">Feb</option>
    <option value="2">Mar</option>
    <option value="3">Apr</option>
    <option value="4">May</option>
    <option value="5">Jun</option>
    <option value="6">Jul</option>
    <option value="7">Aug</option>
    <option value="8">Sep</option>
    <option value="9">Oct</option>
    <option value="10">Nov</option>
    <option value="11">Dec</option>
   </select>
   <label for="year"></label>
   <select class="form-control col-sm-4" name="year" id="year">
   </select>
 </form>
</div>
```

Any suggestion?

Thanks for reading!

Comment: Is there any errors in the console?

Comment: No, it's not anything. It seems like when I click the button to change month, the function $('td').click(function(){ is not working. @CaduDeCastroAlves

Comment: When clicking on either previous or next button, what you expect is that the respective previous or next day should be highlighted?

Comment: When I click previous or next button the "calendar-body" changes, I need to obtain the object clicked with the function $('td').click(function(){, but now is now working. @CaduDeCastroAlves

Comment: $('td').click() only listen to click events on td elements. If you want to get the previous or next td element, you should use a different approach.

Comment: solved.$(document).click(function(event) {
            if ($(event.target).get(0).tagName == 'TD'){
                var text = $(event.target).text();
                $('#calendar-body > tr > td.bg-info').removeClass('bg-info');
                $(event.target).addClass('bg-info');
                console.log(text);
            }
        }); @CaduDeCastroAlves

Comment: Instead of adding and removing the same class, you could simply use jQuery's `toggleClass` method: `$('#calendar-body > tr > td').toggleClass('bg-info');`